# mongodb - check a collection for mutual likes

Tags: mongodb

I had a query that worked before when `likes` collection had users stored as `from` and `to` fields. The query below checked for the two fields and if `like` was true.

Since then I changed the way users are stored in the `likes` collection.

```
.collection('likes')
.aggregate([  {$match: {$and : [{$or: [{from: userId}, {to: userId}]}, {like: true}]}},
{$group: {
    _id: 0,
    from: {$addToSet: "$from"},
    to: {$addToSet: "$to"},
  }
},
{$project: {
    _id: 0,
    users: {
      $filter: {
        input: {$setIntersection: ["$from", "$to"]},
        cond: {$ne: ["$$this", userId]}
      }
    }
  }
},
```

This is how `likes` collection used to store data (and above query worked) in figuring out mutual likers for a `userId` passed in `req.body`

```
{
  "_id": "xw5vk1s_PpJaal46di",
  "from": "xw5vk1s",
   "to": "PpJaal46di"
  "like": true,
}
```

and now I changed users to an array.

```
{
  "_id": "xw5vk1s_PpJaal46di",
  "users": [
    "xw5vk1s",//first element equivalent to from
    "PpJaal46di"//equivalent to previously to
  ],
  "like": true,
}
```

I am not sure how to modify the query to now check for array elements in `users` field now that `from` and `to` is not where the two users liking each other are stored.

Comment: @ray Not sure if project will do this. Its a bit more complicated(for me). Basically the query is doing two things 1)Check all users who were liked by `userId` (first element in `users` is `userId`  2) Get the `second element` from the `users` field of results from 1 above and check if there is a row where they liked back.

Comment: maybe something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gqEH4q2_xU2)? group by `$sortArray` and get count > 1

Comment: @ray That works in the playground but I may need to upgrade mongodb from 4.x to 5.x. Getting error ` Unrecognized expression '$sortArray'`

Comment: maybe checking for sizes of  `$setIntersection` and `$setUnion` is equal to the `users` array itself like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MK8TC6r0njs)?

Comment: @ray I upgraded to version 5.0.13 but still get sortArray error. I tried latest option you suggested above but it has so much of undesired data. Looks like it also outputs the current user `userId`. Your first comment has the right results https://mongoplayground.net/p/20QaqmKxTNp. Can that be replicated without sortarray ?

Comment: `$sortArray` is available only for MongoDB v5.2+. I have provided an answer that use old school `$unwind` and re`$group` to get the array sorted without `$sortArray`

Comment: @ray My Atlas only shows version 5.0.14 can couldn't find a way to upgrade. For the timebeing sticking with version 5.0.14. Will test answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MongoDB v5.2+, you can use `$sortArray` to create a common key for the field `users` and `$group` to get the count. You will get mutual likes by count > 1.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      users: "xw5vk1s"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $sortArray: {
          input: "$users",
          sortBy: 1
        }
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      count: {
        $gt: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gqEH4q2_xU2)

---

Prior to MongoDB v5.2, you can create sorted key for grouping through `$unwind` and `$sort` then `$push` back the `users` in `$group`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      users: "xw5vk1s"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$users"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      users: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      users: {
        $push: "$users"
      },
      like: {
        $first: "$like"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$users",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      count: {
        $gt: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gMBFVqR6pA_)

Comment: The results from two playgrounds above are different. The sortArray results look good but I cant use it. I wish Atlas let me upgrade to a later version than 5.0.14

Comment: I added the following and it worked - `      {$project: {
          _id: 0,
          users: {
            $filter: {
              input: {$setIntersection: ["$users"]},
              cond: {$ne: ["$$this", userId]}
            }
          }
        }
      },`

Comment: @Kal They actually provide the same output if they are given the same sample dataset. Do you have some test cases that the 2 versions behave differently?

Comment: They did show difference in a test case but I did not save it. Anyways I was able to get what I need by adding the `$filter` with `setIntersection`. Will mark this as answer and upvote. Thanks.